# Completion of subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $A$ be a metric subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where we have the euclidean metric.

> How do I prove that $\overline{A}$ with the inclusion map $f:A\hookrightarrow\overline{A}$ is a completion of $A$?

What I have done:
To be completion we must prove all of the following three characteristics:
1 $\overline{A}$ is complete
2 $f$ is an isometry
3 $f(A)$ is dense in $\overline{A}$
As stated in the comments by @Augustin and @Crostul $\overline{A}$ is the smallest *closed* subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that includes $A$, hence $\overline{A}$ is complete as well.
What I'm not sure about is: isn't $f$ the identity in this case, which would mean that it is an isometry?
And how do I prove 3? I know $f(A)=A$, so the closure of $f(A)$ in $\overline{A}$ is simply $\overline{A}$. Is this correct?

Comment: What about a closed subset of a complete set?

Comment: $\bar{A}$ is not the smallest subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that includes $A$, it's the smallest closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that includes $A$. And a closed subset of a complete space is itself complete.

Comment: @TheGovernator If $X$ is a complete metric space (in our case $\Bbb{R}^n$), every closed subset of $X$ is complete as a metric subspace. This shows that $\overline{A}$ is complete (because it is closed).

Comment: @Augustin Ah yes! Thank you

Comment: @Crostul Thank you too

Comment: @The Governator : Your added comments are right. The closure of $A$ in the relative topology of $\overline A$ is still $\overline A$.

Comment: And yes, $f$ is the identity function, which is trivially an isometry.